# Where is it legal to use ruby splat operator?

Tags: ruby, arrays, syntax, operator-precedence, splat

Splats are cool. They're not just for exploding arrays, although that is fun. They can also cast to Array and flatten arrays (See http://github.com/mischa/splat/tree/master for an exhaustive list of what they do.)

It looks like one cannot perform additional operations on the splat, but in 1.8.6/1.9 the following code throws "unexpected tSTAR":

`foo = bar || *zap  #=> unexpected tSTAR`

Whereas this works:

`foo = *zap || bar #=> works, but of limited value`

Where can the splat appear in an expression?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, precedence isn't an issue here, because `foo = bar || (*zap)` works no better.  The general rule of thumb is that you cannot perform additional operations on a splat.  Even something as simple as `foo = (*zap)` is invalid.  This applies to 1.9 as well.

Having said that, what do you expect `foo = bar || *zap` to do, if it worked, that is different than `foo = bar || zap`?  Even in a case like `a, b = bar || *zap` (which also doesn't work), `a, b = bar || zap` accomplishes what I'd assume would be the same thing.

The only situation where this might make any sense is something like `a, b = foo, bar || *zap`.  You should find that most cases where you would want to use this are covered by `a, b = foo, *(bar || zap)`.  If that doesn't cover your case, you should probably ask yourself what you really hope to accomplish by writing such an ugly construct.

---

### EDIT:

In response to your comments, `*zap || bar` is equivalent to `*(zap || bar)`. This demonstrates how low the splat's precedence is. Exactly how low is it? The best answer I can give you is "pretty low".

For an interesting example, though, consider a method `foo` which takes three arguments:

```
def foo(a, b, c)
  #important stuff happens here!
end
```

`foo(*bar = [1, 2, 3])` will splat after the assignment and set the arguments to 1, 2, and 3 respectively.  Compare that with `foo((*bar = [1, 2, 3]))` which will complain about having the wrong number of arguments (1 for 3).

Comment: The example is for illustration only. I accomplished everything I want in life many years ago, and now I simply enjoy discovering the depths of Ruby. Don't you? :)

Comment: Also, is it possible to be more precise? What additional  operation is being performed on the splat in bar || *zap versus *zap || bar?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to mention that: *zap || bar is equivalent to *(zap || bar).  This implies how late the splat binds.  Exactly how late is it?  The best answer I can give you is "pretty late".  For an interesting example, consider a method foo which takes three arguments:  foo(*c = [1, 2, 3]) will splat after the assignment and set the arguments to 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

Comment: Thanks very much Pesto - please can you the stuff about late binding and your example to the top of your answer, then I'll accept it?

Answer (score 9):

The "splat operator" is in fact not an operator at all but a token defined in the Ruby grammar. A read through grammar.y or the Ruby grammar in BNF form* will tell you that it is allowed as the last or only argument:

- in a method definition (except for an optional last `&foo`)
- in a method call (except for an optional last `&foo`)
- on the LHS of as assignment, for example: `a, b, *cs = [1,2,3,4]`
- on the RHS of an assignment, for example: `a, b, c = 1, 2, *[3,4,5]`
- in the when clause of a case statement

Comment: Is this for Ruby 1.8, or Ruby 1.9?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Where can you find Ruby grammar?