# What does the asterisk before the variable mean in the named_scope argument list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I've got a named scope like this:

```
named_scope :by_items, lambda |*items| {
  :joins => :items,
  :conditions => ["items.id in (?)", items.map(&::id)]
}
```

What's the `*item` mean?  When I call it with `Item.find(:first, ...)` it works fine.  If I try to call using a collection, `Item.find(:all, ...)` it fails.

From a different SO question, I know the signature is supposed to be:

```
Order.by_items(item0, item1, ...)
```

So, my question *really* is, how do I turn an Array into a comma separated argument list?

**UPDATE0**

From [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/LiteralMap.html) I've learned:

> (Using a "*" in the argument list helps in working with variable arguments in ruby. In the argument list *disks indicates a vararg. I can then refer to all the disks passed in as an array named "disks". If I call another function with "*disks" the elements of the disks array are passed in as separate arguments.)

**UPDATE1**

More on [the "splat" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776462/where-is-it-legal-to-use-ruby-splat-operator).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`*items` means that the function accepts variable number of arguments. In other words, if you call it like this:

```
Order.by_items(item0, item1, item2)
```

the variable `items` inside the named scope lambda function will be an array with 3 items.

To answer your *real* question, you should call it like this:

```
Order.by_items(*Item.find(:all, ...))
```