# Tricky operators in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I know Ruby has a bunch of useful operators, like `||=`

What other tricky operators does it have?

I haven't found any references for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998/hidden-features-of-ruby. at the very least, check the FAQ section of tag Ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby?sort=faq&pagesize=50

Answer (score 5):

The ampersand at the end of a method signature will grab and expect a block for you.

```
def foo(bar, &block)  
   block.call (bar += 1)  
end
```

The ampersand can also be used in this form to call `to_proc` and let you call the `:address` method with a symbol (example is borrowed from elsewhere)

```
@webs ||= Web.find(:all).index_by &:address
```

The shortcuts like `+=` and `-=` are handy.

Not an operator, so much as another shortcut Rails makes possible. This will get you bar when foo is either `nil?` or `false`

```
a = foo || bar
```

In terms of "operators" I found an (unofficial) thing here for reference: [Ruby operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm)

Comment: Thanks. foo || bar is handy for me

Answer (score 5):

I find that the [splat operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776462/where-is-it-legal-to-use-ruby-splat-operator/777578#777578) is one of the trickiest Ruby operators:

It splits arrays:

```
a,b,c = *[1,2,3]
```

Or builds an array:

```
*a = 1,2,3
```

It can also be used in `case` statement:

```
first = ["one", "two"]
second = ["three", "four"]

case number
  when *first
    "first"
  when *second
    "second"
end
```

It can be used as function argument for varargs:

```
def stuff *args
   args.join('|')
end
```

As it is used for both (splitting and creating arrays), I always have to check the syntax before using it.  It can be used for so many purposes (like converting a hash to an array) that I really find it hard to master.

Comment: WOW ! Splat operator is awesome ! It makes my code really pure. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Both examples work without the splat operator, but a more interesting example is to call a function while "unpacking" the list, e.g., `func(*[1,2,3]).

Comment: Another interesting use for this operator is the partial list unpacking, e.g., `a, *b = [1, 2, 3]`, in which case, `b` is set to `[2, 3]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<=> the "spaceship" or comparison operator
=== the "trequals" or case matching operator
```