# How to make a list in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, list

I'm new at Ruby, and failing to Google this easy question:

What's the normal way to obtain a list of numbers `[1, 2, ..., n]` in Ruby? In Haskell I just type `[1..n]`, and I'm sure that this is easy in Ruby also, but I can't guess it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`1..n` is a [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html) in Ruby. You can convert it to an array using `(1..n).to_a` or the shorter form `[*1..n]`.

Depending on what you're doing, using the Range directly might be more efficient.

Comment: +1 for `[*1..n]`. Do you have a link that explains why it works? I've been looking for that, and `&` too, for quite a while, but I simply can't find a description of those features.

Comment: It's called the Splat operator. More info: http://theplana.wordpress.com/2007/03/03/ruby-idioms-the-splat-operator/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776462/where-is-it-legal-to-use-ruby-splat-operator

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has special range objects, written as `1..10` or whatever. For many purposes you can use one of these instead of an array. If you need the array, call the range object's `to_a` method:

```
(1..10).to_a
```

Comment: How hard was it for Ruby to add 4 more letters to make it `to_array`

Answer (score 1):

You mean a range?  You can do it like this:

`(0..n)`

This will give you an array that has the numbers 0 to 9 in it.

For more information about ranges and arrays, visit here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is

```
1.upto(9).to_a
```

Pretty boring by itself, but you can also do

```
1.step(10, 3).to_a #=> [1, 4, 7, 10]
```