# Understanding ruby splat in ranges and arrays

Tags: ruby, splat

I'm trying to understand the difference between `*(1..9)` and `[*1..9]`

If I assign them to variables they work the same way

```
splat1 = *(1..9)  # splat1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
splat2 = [*1..9]  # splat2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But things get weird when I try to use `*(1..9)` and `[*1..9]` directly.

```
*(1..9).map{|a| a.to_s}  # syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
[*1..9].map{|a| a.to_s}  # ["1", "2", "3"...]
```

I'm guessing part of the problem is with operator precidence? But I'm not exactly sure what's going on. Why am I unable to use `*(1..9)` the same I can use `[*1..9]`?

Comment: `p *(1..9).map{|a| a.to_s}` works ok

Comment: Similarly, `([*1..9]).map` should work fine; however, I think the explicit `to_a` method is more clear and essentially just as concise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the problem is that splat can only be used as an lvalue, that is it has to be received by something.

So your example of `*(1..9).map` fails because there is no recipient to the splat, but the `[*1..9].map` works because the array that you are creating is the recipient of the splat.

UPDATE:
Some more information on this thread (especially the last comment): [Where is it legal to use ruby splat operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776462/where-is-it-legal-to-use-ruby-splat-operator)