# Ruby * operator before array

Tags: ruby, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding ruby splat in ranges and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557382/understanding-ruby-splat-in-ranges-and-arrays)

could anyone tell me what the * does in the following piece of code?

```
line = "name=yabbi;language=ruby;"
Hash[*line.split(/=|;/)]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`*` is the splat operator. It is used to split an array into a list of arguments.

`line.split(/=|;/)` returns an array. To create a Hash, each element of the array must be passed as an individual parameter.

Comment: thanks! just so that I have it clear, all it really does is take that array and turn it into a 'list' of arguments so that the Hash can accept it (in this case anyways, it seems to have many uses)?

Comment: Yup. `Hash[]` does not take arrays as an argument so we have to "explode" the elements into individual parameters.

Answer (score 1):

it's a [splat operator](http://theplana.wordpress.com/2007/03/03/ruby-idioms-the-splat-operator/) Read about it. Often times you see it used when you want to split up an array to use as parameters of a function.