# what happens when *args is passed to yield in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield, form-for

what happens when *args passed to yield in ruby, in capture_helper.rb of rails I saw a statement where *args is passed to yield statement, what actually happens when we do so.

```
 buffer = with_output_buffer { value = yield(*args) }
```

where first parameter is builder object and second parameter is the block passed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is it legal to use ruby splat operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776462/where-is-it-legal-to-use-ruby-splat-operator)

Comment: *args specifies the variable length argument.

Answer (score 2):

With the `*` operator ([splat operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html)) prefixing a variable (which must be an array or hash), the values of the array are extracted:

```
ary = [1, 2, 3]

def foo(a, b, c)
  a + b + c
end

foo(ary)
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3)

foo(*ary)
# 6
```

It's just the same with `yield`, except that the values are passed to the block:

```
def bar
  ary2 = [5, 6]
  yield(*ary2)
end

bar do |x, y|
  puts x + y
end
# 11
```

Comment: but, most of code i have seen, * is used in method definition to accept any number of parameters rather than argument list

Answer (score 0):

Splats have many uses in ruby. When you use a splat in a method call it turns an array into a list of arguments.

```
def test(*args)
  args
end
```

Consider these examples:

```
a = [1,2,3]
test(a)
# => [[1, 2, 3]]
test(1,2,3)
# => [1, 2, 3]
test(*a)
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

In the first example the array is treated as the first argument so the result is an array in an array. While `*[1,2,3]` de-structures the array so that we get the desired result.

This makes it extremely useful for calling methods that take a variable number of arguments. `yield` works just like any other method in this regard, as using a splat will de-structure the array in `args` and call the passed block with a list of arguments.